# How to read an excel file with nested columns in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Using Pandas, I'm trying to read an excel file that looks like the following:

[image: sample]

another sample [image: sample 2]

I tried to read the excel file using the regular approach by running: `df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', skiprows=6)`.

But the problem with it is that I don't get all the columns names needed and most of the column names are Unnamed:1

Is there a way to solve these and read all the columns? Or an approach were I can convert it to a json file

Comment: Not sure it will completly solve your problem, but you can try: `pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', skiprows=6, header=[7, 8,9])`

Comment: @Renaud Thanks for your reply! I've tried what you've suggested before, but it doesn't read all the column names and most column names are Unnamed.